# Using NotifcationCenter in another class causes unrecognized selector in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create another class and set NotificationCenter to make view up when keyboard shows. I tried to give UIViewController as argument. But I caught error that unrecognized selector sent to instance. Why the selector comes being unrecognized and how should I do?

- ViewController

```
   class ViewController: UIViewController {

     override func viewDidLoad() {
          bringFunc.upWithKeyboard(VC: self)
       }
   }
```

- CustomClass

```
    class bringFunc {

        static  var view: UIView!
        static func upWithKeyboard(VC: UIViewController) {

            view = VC.view
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(VC, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name:UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)

             NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(VC, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

        }

        @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification){

            guard let rect = (notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue, let duration = notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? TimeInterval else{return}

            UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) {
             let transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -(rect.size.height/1.5))
                bringFunc.view.transform = transform

            }

         }

        @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification){
            guard let duration = notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? TimeInterval else{return}

            UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) {
                let transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
                bringFunc.view.transform = transform

            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is fixed variant (for whatever reason such design is chosen)

```
class bringFunc {

        static  var view: UIView!
        class func upWithKeyboard(VC: UIViewController) {

            view = VC.view
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name:UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)

             NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

        }

        @objc class func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification){

            guard let rect = (notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue, let duration = notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? TimeInterval else{return}

            UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) {
             let transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -(rect.size.height/1.5))
                bringFunc.view.transform = transform

            }

         }

        @objc class func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification){
            guard let duration = notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? TimeInterval else{return}

            UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) {
                let transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
                bringFunc.view.transform = transform

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I want to put together those function to avoid redundant code. I called `upWithKeyboard()` making instance but it didn't work...